# Running a QT application from Command promt in WIndows

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qtgui, qmainwindow

I have made a small QT application and i am trying to run it thru command prompt on Windows:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QMainWindow a(argc,argv)
    QLabel *NewLabel = new QLabel("Hi i am a label");
    NewLabel->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

after doing `qmake -project`
and then `qmake -TestPrg.pro`
then i try `make`,here it fails with following error:

```
D:\TestPrg>make
make -f Makefile.Debug
make[1]: Entering directory `D:/TestPrg'
Makefile.Debug:58: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/TestPrg'
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

If we look at `makefile.debug` ,line number 58 and add a TAB before "<<",it complains at someother line number.So i feel there is something wrong in the compiler options ,can someone guide how to make it working.

Thanks alot

Comment: More likely it is there are multiple errors in the Makefile.
Can you update with the makefile.debug and also what is the second error it throws?

Comment: `qmake -TestPrg.pro` is wrong. Just use `qmake` or `qmake TestPrg.pro`.

Comment: QMainWindow a(argc,argv) -> change it to QApplication a(argc, argv)

Comment: @Laslo typo mistake i used qmake TestPrg.pro only.

Comment: ####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cc .cxx

{.}.cpp{debug\}.obj::
 $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
 $<
<<

{.}.cc{debug\}.obj::
 $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
 $<
<<

{.}.cxx{debug\}.obj::
 $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
 $<
<<

{.}.c{debug\}.obj::
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
 $<
<<

{.}.cpp{debug\}.obj::
 $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
 $<
<<

{.}.cc{debug\}.obj::
 $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
 $<
<<

Comment: @Wagmare:Even that didnt help

Comment: Looks to me that you're mixing mingw-make and nmake. (Probably generating makefiles for nmake but executing mingw-make). Try `nmake` (in a VS prompt), or make sure that you're using a Qt build for mingw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just made an example work on my machine. The code goes below, but you have at least a few mistakes, namely:

- You use QMainWindow for being the application as it seems as opposed to QApplication. That is not going to compile.
- Respectively, you would need to include QApplication rather than QMainWindow.
- You miss a semi-colon after the first statement in the main function.
- You construct a `QLabel` on the heap needlessly. In this particular scenario, it could be a simple stack object.
- You use invoking qmake as `qmake -foo` rather than just `qmake` or `make foo`.
- You are trying to use "make" in the Windows Command prompt as opposed to `nmake` or `jom`. If you use Visual Studio and MSVC, do not mix it with mingw, cygwin and other things. Just use nmake, otherwise, yes, use make for the latter options.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel NewLabel("Hi i am a label");
    NewLabel.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
* qmake
* nmake
* main.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,but here is what is used on my command prompt:D:\TestPrg>qmake -project

D:\TestPrg>qmake TestPrg.pro

D:\TestPrg>make
make -f Makefile.Debug
make[1]: Entering directory `D:/TestPrg'
Makefile.Debug:58: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/TestPrg'
make: *** [debug] Error 2

Comment: @user3156680: please try again with a clean environment. Also, you have not paid attention to the "nmake" note I wrote.

Comment: i cannot use "nmake" ,'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user3156680: you have not set up the path. You could run the Visual Studio prompt to get over this, but really: are you using MSVC or mingw? You have not made it clear yet...

Comment: I am using MSVC and in the env variables i have QMAKESPEC as "win 32-msvc.net" .unfortunately if i try to use VS2010 commmand prompt instead of opening a command prompt window it opens this folder location"C:\Windows\System32",i have no idea why

Comment: @user3156680: navigate to the proper location with the `cd` command.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more ...i am sorry but i am new to running a QT application from command prompt

Comment: It has not much to do with Qt. Type `cd C:\Path\To\Your\Project and then run qmake and nmake in there in the Visual Studio prompt.

Comment: D:\testPrg>qmake -project

D:\testPrg>qmake testPrg.pro

D:\testPrg>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1065: invalid option '-'
Stop.

It didn't work

Comment: You do not need qmake -project, just qmake, and use my project file. Also, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94786 Also, which Qt version have you downloaded? Please give me a link.

Comment: I am using QT4.3.0 ..i dont have download link right now.But still the issue persists ,please help

Comment: So finally some success,in my debug folder I am able to generate my .exe file.I agree with you that it is very ancient but the project i am working it has a lot of legacy code written in QT 4.3.0 ,so that's why I have to use the same .

Comment: and the issue was related to MAKEFLAGS which was pointing to a Qnx directory.Thanks Laszlo

Comment: Yes, I read posts about that the other day. I was going to suggest that once the mingw/msvc is fixed. Glad, it is working now. You are welcome. :)